# Recvfrom won't read zero byte

Tags: c++, udp

I have udp server and client. I have to write client which send four bytes, first of which is zero(0x00). Here comes my problem with recvfrom, which I beleave somehow stop reading from socket file descriptor when symbol is 0, 0x00, 00 .
Here is the client code:

```
#include "udp_client.h"
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
  
#define PORT     5001
#define MAXLINE  1024
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int send_udp_packet(BYTE *msg, size_t len)
{
   int sockfd;
   char buffer[MAXLINE];
   struct sockaddr_in   servaddr;
  
   if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
       perror("socket creation failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  
   memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
      
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.13");
      
   int n;
      
   sendto(sockfd, (const char *)msg, len,
       MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
       sizeof(servaddr));
 
   printf("Message sent.\n");
 
   close(sockfd);
   return 0;
}
 
int main(void)
{
   BYTE msg[4]={1, 0x04, 0x02, 0x03};
   send_udp_packet(msg, strlen((const char *)msg));
  
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Side note: Never ignore the return value of networking functions. They contain information critical to proper program operation.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` is the wrong function to determine the size of a byte array, especially if it contains `0x00` bytes.  That function is designed for **null-terminated** strings, not byte arrays.

In the example provided, use `sizeof()` instead:

`send_udp_packet(msg, sizeof(msg));`